# Jittery sound, fixed by reboot, with Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: audio

Sometimes, after booting, my sound is jittery and youtube videos are jumpy.

If I reboot, this usually (but not always) goes away.

What could cause this? Is there a log I can look at that might help to identify the failure?

EDIT:

This might have fixed it:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall alsa-base pulseaudio
pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload
```

Source: https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/

I will wait for another failure, and then try the fix again next time I get the sound problem.

Comment: I've got the same issue with my PC - most likely some timing bug in the ALSA HDA audio driver or PulseAudio. I can fix it without a reboot by removing all the modules responsible for sound and then loading them back which is quite annoying. Some workarounds are listed here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Advanced_Linux_Sound_Architecture/Troubleshooting and https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting#Glitches,_skips_or_crackling

Comment: Is this only in your browser, or is sound/video a problem when played from local sources with local applications?

Comment: @KGIII In my case it affects Chrome and Firefox but audacious and mpv work just fine.

Comment: Try disabling 'hardware acceleration' in your browser(s). You'll have to restart the browsers to see if it has any effect.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I have not had the problem today, but will try those solutions next time it occurs.

Comment: Please be sure to followup. If it does work, I can write an answer and it'll get archived for others in the future - which is actually a big part of what these fora are for.

Comment: I editted my /etc/pulse/default.pa file, adding tsched=0 to the end of the line beginning with "load-module module-udev-detect". I then did "pulseaudio -k" and "pulseaudio --start". Unfortunately, the problem did not go away. ;{

Comment: I tried disabling "hardware acceleration" in my browser. That did not work either. I don't think it is a browser problem. As when I change my volume setting in Ubuntu I get a little sound. That sounds is corrupted too.

Comment: I also tried setting "tsched=1". but that didn't help.

Comment: I don't know whether or not this could be a useful clue, but when the problem occurs youtube videos keep pausing/jumping too.

Comment: I've had the problem even more today, following Linux updates.. I thought it was a system-wide problem. But if I open a VirtualBox, the sounds works fine from that. Just not in the host system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title says :

> Jittery sound

My question : [Are you sure it is *jittering* ? I mean not a *latency* problem.](https://headfonics.com/what-is-jitter-in-audio/) This link should help you analysing.

A/ If it is authentic sound jittering then... the problem is with the clocksource.
Depending on the configuration of your system (PREEMPT /HZ / NOHZ / NOHZ_FULL / cpu isolation...) the clock chosen as reference might not be reliable. Under a default kernel configuration, most MIDI sequencers will complain about it.

Human ears can detect jittering from 6ms shitfs.

B/ If it is latency, then the problem is at first with your sound server (pulseaudio as I can read in OP's comments) and second with your scheduler. As I knew it, pulseaudio is not a real-time sound server (I mean as *jack* can be, launched SCHED_RR) and your cpu (paticularly in cpu isolation conditions / irq threaded) might well be bothered with plenty of other things.

Exceptional ears (especially trained) can detect latency starting from 6ms shifts, audiophile connoisseurs are happy with 10ms latencies et most users of 48K audio 16bits sources wont detect anything below 16ms.

With the link I mentioned and of course taking care to choose a far more reliable sound source than chrome can be... (it should not be that difficult... ;-) the standard *aplay* can be considered as a good start), play some standard .wav (not needing any sort of cpu/gpu hungry decoder) push a step further in the analysis of your sound, is it A or B ? What are your kernel config parameters regarding the options I listed above ?...) I'll elaborate afterwards.

Comment: I don't think it's latency. If I change the volume using the slider in the top right of my Gnome desktop, it also makes the jittery sound. But thanks for the detailed response!

Comment: This didn't fix it, but it helped me get there. Solution is in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

My sound an video was jittery only using YouTube. Tried so many different things. All I had to do was change a setting in Firefox. In Privacy and security Firefox was blocking all video and sound from unknown source. I changed it to allow all video and audio. No more problems.....for now.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note that the OP does not make any mention about Firefox being the application that showed jittery video.